# oracle integrity constraint

Tags: oracle

This is my first time using Oracle.

I inserted something into the db manually:

```
insert into ATTR_TYPE_VALUE (ATTR_TYPE_ID, VALID_VALUE, CREATED_BY) 
(select ATTR_TYPE_ID, 'Ad', 2 from ATTR_TYPE where VALUE = 'ind')
```

And I got the following error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-02291: integrity constraint
>   (LO.ATTR_TYPE_VALUE_FK02) violated - parent key not found

Here is what I found upon research:

For an insert statement, this ORA-02291 error is common when you are trying to insert a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.  In that case, you need to add the parent row to the table and then re-insert your child table row.

Does this mean that the `VALUE='ind'` does not exist in the `ATTR_TYPE` table?

Comment: What all values you want to insert? I'm not sure if thats the correct syntax. Provide the schemas of both the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What columns is `ATTR_TYPE_VALUE_FK02` defined on and what tables and columns are you referencing?

```
SELECT fk_columns.table_name,
       fk_columns.column_name,
       fk_columns.position,
       pk_columns.table_name,
       pk_columns.column_name,
       pk_columns.position
  FROM all_constraints fk_constraint,
       all_cons_columns fk_columns,
       all_cons_columns pk_columns
 WHERE fk_constraint.owner             = 'LO'
   AND fk_constraint.constraint_name   = 'ATTR_TYPE_VALUE_FK02'
   AND fk_constraint.owner             = fk_columns.owner
   AND fk_constraint.constraint_name   = fk_columns.constraint_name
   AND fk_constraint.r_owner           = pk_columns.owner
   AND fk_constraint.r_constraint_name = pk_columns.constraint_name
```

Comment: Is that a _gasp_ implicit join ;)?

Comment: @Ben - That's what you get when you dig up queries you wrote when dinosaurs roamed the Earth and SQL 99 join syntax wasn't supported. :-)