# SQL Error 02291 - Issues with foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ora-02291

We are trying to insert data to our tables, however we have run into an error and can't see the problem. This is what we are getting -

> INSERT INTO Item(Manifest_barcode,Trip_ID,Item_weight,Pickup_customer,Delivery_customer,Category) VALUES (159601450,73495,2156,166,184,'A')
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.SYS_C009055) violated - parent key not found
>   02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"

We have checked the order of the creation of the tables, and as far as we can tell everything is in the right place. All of the foreign keys seem to be correct as well.

This is how we are dropping/creating the tables -

```
DROP TABLE Item;
DROP TABLE Trip;
DROP TABLE Vehicle;
DROP TABLE Vehicle_Type;
DROP TABLE Employee;
DROP TABLE Customer;
DROP TABLE Category;

CREATE TABLE Category(
    Category VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Requirements VARCHAR2(100),

    PRIMARY KEY(Category)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
  Reference INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Town VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Post_code VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
  Telephone INT NOT NULL,
  Contact_first_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Contact_last_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(Reference)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee(
  Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
  First_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Last_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  NI_No VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Telephone VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Mobile VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Hazardous_goods VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(Employee_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle_Type(
    Vehicle_Type_ID VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Make VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(Vehicle_Type_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle(
  Registration VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Vehicle_Type_ID VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  GVW VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  Vehicle_Year INT NOT NULL,
  Body VARCHAR2(100),

  PRIMARY KEY(Registration),
   FOREIGN KEY(Vehicle_Type_ID) REFERENCES Vehicle_Type(Vehicle_Type_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Trip(
    Trip_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Departure_date VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Return_date VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_registration VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(Trip_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Employee_no) REFERENCES Employee(Employee_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Item(
    Manifest_barcode VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    Trip_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Item_weight INT NOT NULL,
    Pickup_customer INT NOT NULL,
    Delivery_customer INT NOT NULL,
    Category VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(Manifest_barcode),
    FOREIGN KEY(Trip_ID) REFERENCES Trip(Trip_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Category) REFERENCES Category(Category)
);
```

This is how the items are being inserted -

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name,Reference,Address,Town,Post_code,Telephone,Contact_first_name,Contact_last_name,Email) VALUES
('Calash Ltd.',1,'88 Rinkomania Lane','Cardigan','SA55 8BA',11671595763,'Cameron','Dunnico','c.dunnico@calash.co.uk');

INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_no,First_name,Last_name,NI_No,Telephone,Mobile,Hazardous_goods) VALUES
(0045619,'Eamon','O''Looney','JJ 56 53 26 B','1656727840','76599770175','N');

INSERT INTO Vehicle_Type (Vehicle_Type_ID,Model,Make) VALUES
(1,'RIEVER','ALBION');

INSERT INTO Vehicle(Registration,Vehicle_Type_ID,GVW,Vehicle_Year,Body) VALUES
('4585 AW',1,20321,1963,'');

INSERT INTO Category (Category, Description, Requirements) VALUES
('A','Normal','');

INSERT INTO Trip(Trip_ID,Departure_date,Return_date,Employee_no,Vehicle_registration) VALUES
(72943,'40910','40914',0028539,'BR58BXE');

INSERT INTO Item(Manifest_barcode,Trip_ID,Item_weight,Pickup_customer,Delivery_customer,Category) VALUES
(541769754,73421,3629,44,145,'A');
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which FK is HR.SYS_C009055?

Comment: You either don't have a TRIP record with ID 73495, or don't have a CATEGORY record with 'A'. If you had named constraints it would be easier to tell which, but you can check in the data dictionary (all_cons_columns etc.) to see which constraint has that system-generated name. You haven't shown the other tables being populated so we don't know what data exists.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've edited the question and added the rest of the data.

Comment: @jarlh How would I check what foreign key `HR.SYS_C009055` is?

Comment: The two TRIP_ID values in your example inserts don't match. Are these the only rows you've created?

Comment: Alex Poole's comment says "you can check in the data dictionary (all_cons_columns etc.) to see which constraint has that system-generated name". Or, even better, specify constraint names in the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @AlexPoole The inserts in the question are only examples, there are others that do match.

Comment: @user3746428 - the error you're getting disagrees. Either you are not creating a matching parent key in one of those tables before creating the item; or you are creating them but in a different session and the item insert can't see the parent data in the other session because it hasn't been committed. (That seems less likely but from the 'we' in the question  it's a possibility worth mentioning).

Comment: @user3746428 - also [here's a query to examine an FK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442294/266304); or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6507175/266304) shows everything for a table. And if you are providing sample data then make it relevant - show what you think is the related data in each table, not random rows form each table, which doesn't help. (I expect if you try to find the related data you'll spot the mistake anyway)

Comment: That isn't really a duplicate; same error but in that case they were trying to create the child before the parent, while you aren't creating the parent at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your full insert script has 13 inserts into the `item` table with `trip_id` 73495. Your error is being thrown from the first one:

```
INSERT INTO Item(Manifest_barcode,Trip_ID,Item_weight,Pickup_customer,Delivery_customer,Category)
VALUES (159601450,73495,2156,166,184,'A');
```

Your script does *not* have a matching insert for the `trip` table. You have IDs either side:

```
INSERT INTO Trip(Trip_ID,Departure_date,Return_date,Employee_no,Vehicle_registration)
VALUES (73494,'40994','40995',0077517,'PY11 OAA');
INSERT INTO Trip(Trip_ID,Departure_date,Return_date,Employee_no,Vehicle_registration)
VALUES (73496,'40994','41000',0083413,'PY58 UHF');
```

But there is not one for ID 73495.

Searching that script for 73495 only matches those 13 `item` inserts, and a later item which has a `manifest_barcode` of 617349505 which contains it. But that is all.

There is no matching trip, which is what the exception is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the following

you have inserted this row in the employee table with employee_no=0045619

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_no,First_name,Last_name,NI_No,Telephone,Mobile,Hazardous_goods) VALUES
(0045619,'Eamon','O''Looney','JJ 56 53 26 B','1656727840','76599770175','N');
```

trip is the table which was referencing the employee table

```
INSERT INTO Trip(Trip_ID,Departure_date,Return_date,Employee_no,Vehicle_registration) VALUES
(72943,'40910','40914',0028539,'BR58BXE');
```

in this insert statement you had **inserted a row with employee_no=0028539**, ***which was not matched with the employee_no(0045619) available in the employee table***.
please correct the value and try to insert with the same employee number in the employee table

---------editied----------------

check the tripid in item(73421) is available in the trip table?

Comment: There is a lot more data that matches. The data inserted in the question is just an example of each.

Comment: The error is coming from the `item` insert, which means it's one of its two FKs which doesn't have a parent; not the employee/trip relationship. Working with partial data isn't helping though *8-)

Comment: @user3746428 can you check whether the trip_id value in the item table is exist in the trip table?

Comment: @AlexPoole i tried with the given statements in the question since i got the   error i informed him

Comment: I understand that, but the OP had already commented that "The inserts in the question are only examples, there are others that do match". Which isn't helpful of course...

Comment: @AlexPoole I didn't want to post the full set of data because of the length, but you can view it on Google Drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qYGvsKpcb7dGhva0NxbGQ2TUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks, i didn't see that statement in the question